# L296N to Raspberry Pi pins disanbiguisation

Tags: gpio, driver

I have some concerns with the L296N module.

Let's consider the below module notation.

1. I understand what all the connections do except the pair (7 and above) and (12 and above).
   Let's consider only the pair 7 and above(7b).
   To what should be 7 and 7b connected? To two different GPIO or to GPIO and GND?
2. Why do they need 2 pins for the motor direction?Souldn't be only one enough since there are only two directions?(HIGH-HIGH and LOW-LOW encodings are not used).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you refer to as 7b and 12b are 5V pins and should NEVER be connected to a Pi GPIO which are only tolerant of 3.3V.

Pins 7 and 12 are enable pins and enable motor A and motor B respectively.  Generally it's simplest to connect a jumper between 7-7b and 12-12B so that motors A and B are permanently enabled.

Why two pins per motor?  Why not?  That's how the chip/module is designed.

```
8 9 (or 10 11 for motor B)
| |
0 0 free wheel (not driven)
0 1 clockwise
1 0 counter clockwise
1 1 active brake
```

[image: L298N module]

Comment: Thank you very much, thus LOW-LOW and HIGH-HIGH are used as brake and free whekk commands.

Comment: @CosminMihai Yes, LOW/LOW is no power and no brake, HIGH/HIGH is no power but there is a brake effect (I don't know what causes the brake effect).